# How do I programmatically tell Logback to Reload Configuration

Tags: java, logging, logback

I know there's a reloadDefaultConfiguration() jmx operation, but without getting an instance of MBean and invoking this operation, is there a Logback api to reload the default configuration (optionally specifying a log configuration file path)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the source code of `JMXConfigurator.reloadDefaultConfiguration()`:

```
public void reloadDefaultConfiguration() throws JoranException {
  ContextInitializer ci = new ContextInitializer(loggerContext);
  URL url = ci.findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile(true);
  loggerContext.reset();
  ci.configureByResource(url);
}
```

What about just running this code wherever you need it?

The only problem is the `loggerContext` variable. You can obtain it using:

```
(LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there is well-factored API to do this, what about raising an [issue](http://jira.qos.ch/browse)? Also are you aware that Logback has a built-in auto-refreshing feature?

Comment: Yea, thought about using the auto-refreshing feature but seams a bit scary to enable it on anything other than my dev environment

Answer (score 15):

I used the following code for this purpose:

```
public static void reloadLogger() {
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    ContextInitializer ci = new ContextInitializer(loggerContext);
    URL url = ci.findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile(true);

    try {
        JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
        configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
        loggerContext.reset();
        configurator.doConfigure(url);
    } catch (JoranException je) {
        // StatusPrinter will handle this
    }
    StatusPrinter.printInCaseOfErrorsOrWarnings(loggerContext);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle configuring logback using a .groovy file ...throws `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException`

Comment: The groovy problem is annoying.  I'm trying to restart my system mid-run, and I would like to reload the groovy file, since it puts the log files into a time-stamped directory.

Comment: FYI this no longer works since logback 1.3 because of a breaking API change in [LOGBACK-1655](https://jira.qos.ch/projects/LOGBACK/issues/LOGBACK-1655)