# Logback configuration is coming as null

Tags: java, logback, dropwizard

I am using logback 1.2.3. I am passing the logback configuration as `-Dlogback.configurationFile=$SERVICE_PATH/restapilayer.logback.xml`

My `restapilayer.logback.xml` looks like below

```
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <Target>System.out</Target>
            <encoder>
               <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

In my logs also I am seeing the configuration file being loaded.

```
10:51:42,695 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [/home/ubuntu/build-target/restapilayer/restapilayer.logback.xml] at [file:/home/ubuntu/build-target/restapilayer/restapilayer.logback.xml]
10:51:42,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
10:51:42,863 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
10:51:42,869 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
10:51:42,894 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
10:51:42,895 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
10:51:42,895 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
10:51:42,896 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@3fd7a715 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
2018-01-13 10:51:42 [main] INFO  com.vnera.common.utils.CommonUtils - adding uncaught exception handler hook...
INFO [2018-01-13 10:51:44] o.e.j.u.log:[?:?:?] - [main] - Logging initialized @1792ms
```

Then while trying to log I am seeing the logback configuration as null and it seems logback is running with default config

```
INFO [2018-01-12 16:25:34] c.v.r.c.v.r.VneraBackendService:[?:?:?] - [main] - Logback used _null_ as the configuration file_
```

I am using the below code to get the logback config

```
logger.debug("Testing Debug logging");
LoggerContext loggerContext = ((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)logger).getLoggerContext();
URL mainURL = ConfigurationWatchListUtil.getMainWatchURL(loggerContext);
System.out.println(mainURL);
// or even
logger.info("Logback used '{}' as the configuration file.", mainURL);
```

Can someone let me know what is going wrong? How can I debug this issue?

Maven dependency tree is added [here](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2018-January/004964.html).

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use logback (with `logback.xml`) with a dropwizard application. During application initialization whenever `io.dropwizard.Application.run(BackendServiceConfiguration, Environment)` was getting called it was throwing away the logger previously initialized and trying to use the logger defined in the dropwizard configuration file (`config.yaml`).

To get around this after the `run()` I had to call the below code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354238/785523).

```
public static void relaodLogback() {
        String loggingConfig = System.getProperty("logback.configurationFile");
        if(loggingConfig == null) {
            System.out.println("Logging Config is null");
        }

        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        loggerContext.reset();
        JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();

        try {
            InputStream configStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(loggingConfig));
            configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
            configurator.doConfigure(configStream); // loads logback file
            configStream.close();
            System.out.println("Loaded configuration file");
        } catch (JoranException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to log configuration file");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```