# How to use Spring environment values from config server in Logstash Encoder of Logback

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, logstash-logback-encoder

I would like to use Spring environment values as [custom fields in the Logstash encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#custom-fields) of a Logback appender.

There is a general configuration tag to use properties

```
<property resource="logstash.properties" />
```

And there is a [special configuration tag from Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_environment_properties) for this purpose

```
<springProperty name="appEnv" source="environment"/>
```

The properties of both tags can then be used in the [custom fields of the Logstash encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#custom-fields)

```
<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
    <customFields>{"application.environment":"${appEnv}"</customFields>
</encoder>
```

Problem is, as far as I understand, that this only works under certain circumstances. The problem is probably that **Logback has already finished configuring when the Spring environment is built**.

It seems to work when

- The property is local and static (available on configuration time)
- The property is in bootstrap.properties

It seems NOT to work when

- The property is dynamic as when retrieved from **Spring config server**

My property values delivered from config server are `null` when Logback is configured and therefore the log shows them as `appEnv_IS_UNDEFINED` for a property called `appEnv`.

Because most examples just use the `spring.application.name` this seems to be mostly unnoticed.

To solve the timing problem, I searched for a way to **reload the Logback configuration** `onApplicationEvent`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47814780/8035582) that confirms my problem and offers a skeleton solution.

I found other solutions where the Logback appender that uses the Logstash encoder is completely programmatically built and added to the `LoggerContext`.

However, I wonder if there is also a way to stick with the XML configuration of the appender and **"just reload" the config programmatically when the Spring environment is ready**. How would I do this?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354238/8035582) to do the reload, but it does not work for my case. The `appEnv_IS_UNDEFINED` continue to appear in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by implementing a Spring [`ApplicationContextInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html).

In the called `initialize` method I can access my Logback Appender and Encoder via RootLogger.

```
Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
RollingFileAppender jsonFileAppender = (RollingFileAppender) rootLogger.getAppender(LOGSTASH_APPENDER_NAME);
LogstashEncoder encoder = (LogstashEncoder) jsonFileAppender.getEncoder();
```

From the LogstashEncoder, I can get the customFields

```
String customFields = encoder.getCustomFields();
```

And there I found the unresolved properties in the JSON String as expected

```
{"application.environment":"appEnv_IS_UNDEFINED"}
```

Since I can get the built Spring `Environment` from the passed `ApplicationContext`

```
springEnvironment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
```

I can match unresolved properties with the Regex `(\w+)_IS_UNDEFINED` and replace them with the real value from the Spring Environment.

Surprisingly, I **do not need to reload or restart anything**. It is sufficent to **just set the fixed customFields on the Encoder**. Immediately after, the Log messages contain the correct values.

```
encoder.setCustomFields(fixedCustomFields);
```

With this Initializer in place, I can fully configure my appender and the LogstashEncoder in `logback-spring.xml` or an included file.