# How do I programmatically tell Logback 1.4.x to Reload Configuration

Tags: java, logging, logback, logback-classic

How do I programmatically tell Logback 1.4.x to Reload Configuration?

I found an answer to [reload logback 1.2.x configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320133/how-do-i-programmatically-tell-logback-to-reload-configuration/77170861) but it doesn't work with logback 1.4.x (nor 1.3.x) as it gives a compilation error:

`The method findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile(boolean) is undefined for the type ContextInitializer`

Comment: It *looks* like you might want just `ci.autoConfig()` (on `ContextInitializer`). Can you try it? After some digging, I found that method was removed by [LOGBACK-1655](https://jira.qos.ch/projects/LOGBACK/issues/LOGBACK-1655). The relevant commit is here: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/fa3de693048d25698af7264fd294a1c9ba6940d1 which might give some idea how they intended it to be replaced. Really they should provide some migration guide if they plan to make breaking API changes, but I don't see anything like that.

Comment: An alternative is polling: [Automatically reloading configuration file upon modification](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan)

Comment: Thanks Michael, that seems to work :)

Answer (score 2):

In Logback 1.4.x, the method `findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile(boolean)` is indeed not available. Instead, Logback 1.4.x introduced a new way to programmatically reload its configuration using the LoggerContext class. To programmatically trigger a configuration reload, you can use the following approach:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator;
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException;

public class LogbackConfigReload {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogbackConfigReload.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

        try {
            JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
            configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
            loggerContext.reset();

            // Reload the configuration from the default configuration file
            configurator.doConfigure("logback.xml"); // <<< REPLACE THE FILENAME

            logger.info("Configuration reloaded successfully");
        } 
        catch (JoranException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to reload config", e);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code:

1. I obtain the LoggerContext using LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory().
2. I create a JoranConfigurator and set it to work with the LoggerContext.
3. I call loggerContext.reset() to reset the context, which clears the previous configuration.
4. I use configurator.doConfigure("logback.xml") to reload the configuration from the specified file (replace "logback.xml" with the path to your Logback configuration file).

Finally, I log a message to indicate that the configuration was reloaded.

Comment: Thanks. It does mean that I have to know what is the filename for logback instead of having it finding it. For instance, if test environment uses a different configuration file, we can use java option `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/test-logback.xml`. I could look for it but it means if logback does another breaking change, I have to remember to change the java code. Having logback returning the file (as it did with `findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile`) was theoretically less error prone...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898563/michael) for pointing out `ci.autoConfig()`, it does seem to work...

```java
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; // I'm using slf4j + logback

[..]

    public void resetLogger() {
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        loggerContext.reset();

        ContextInitializer ci = new ContextInitializer(loggerContext);
        ci.autoConfig();
    }
```